# Rendering button based on user profile

Tags: apex, visualforce

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!Submit}" rendered="{!CanSubmit}" />
```

Currently I have this following code in my Apex:

```
 public boolean CanSubmit
 {
 get
   {            
     if(employee.Status__c == EmployeeStatus.get('Submit').getValue())
     {
       return true;
     }
     else
     {
       return false;
     }          
   }
 }
```

Now, I need to add few more condition to the Submit button whether to show the button but I'm not sure how to achieve this since I already have `rendered={!CanSubmit}`, how should I add extra condition to `rendered`?

```
rendered="{!IF($Profile.Name =='System Administrator'||$Profile.Name =='Sales Manager', true , false)}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try out like this:

```
rendered="{!(($Profile.Name =='System Administrator'||$Profile.Name =='Sales Manager') && CanSubmit)}"
```

Comment: Always replace `IF(condition, true, false)` with simply `condition`.

Comment: @AdrianLarson: I didn't  quite get

Comment: Updated the answer, eliminating IF condition.

Comment: ah, got it now..

Comment: @NickKahn is that working correctly?